# Как изменить css для form, когда :focus на input внутри него

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть вот такая форма:

```css
.header-search {
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #ff000080;
}
.header-icon.header-search__icon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.header-search__input {
  border: none;
  /* outline: none; */
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.header-search__input::placeholder {
  color: #BDBDBD;
  font-family: 'Raleway', 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.header-search {
  width: 160px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<form action="search" class="header-search">
  <input type="text" class="header-search__input" placeholder="Поиск">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/vs0dmRq/search.png" class="header-search__icon header-icon" alt="">
</form>
```

как сделать так, чтобы при фокусе на `.header-search__input`, цвета фона `.header-search` поменялся на синий.


*upd: желательно с анимацией*

*upd: хотелось бы чисто на css. но если критично можно и js*

Comment: на css это не сделать потому, что там указывается последовательность от предка к детям, но не наоборот

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На *CSS* это не сделать потому, что там указывается последовательность от предка к детям, но не наоборот

```js
document.querySelector('.header-search__input').addEventListener('focus', function(e){
    document.querySelector('.header-search').classList.toggle("mystyle");
}, true);

document.querySelector('.header-search__input').addEventListener('blur', function(e){
    document.querySelector('.header-search').classList.toggle("mystyle");
}, true);
```

```css
.header-search {
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #ff000080;
  
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  -ms-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
}
.header-icon.header-search__icon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.header-search__input {
  border: none;
  /* outline: none; */
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.header-search__input::placeholder {
  color: #BDBDBD;
  font-family: 'Raleway', 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.header-search {
  width: 160px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.mystyle {
   background-color: blue;      
}
```

```html
<form action="search" class="header-search">
  <input type="text" class="header-search__input" placeholder="Поиск">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/vs0dmRq/search.png" class="header-search__icon header-icon" alt="">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать псевдо-класс [:focus-within](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within), если устаревшие браузеры не нужны. Поддержка уже во всех современных браузерах. Но есть нюанс - нельзя указать что именно внутри формы должно быть в фокусе, будет реагировать на что угодно в фокусе.

```css
.header-search {
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #ff000080;
  transition: background-color 0.5s linear;
}

.header-search:focus-within {
  background-color: #0000ff;
}

.header-icon.header-search__icon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.header-search__input {
  border: none;
  /* outline: none; */
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.header-search__input::placeholder {
  color: #BDBDBD;
  font-family: 'Raleway', 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.header-search {
  width: 160px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<form action="search" class="header-search">
  <input type="text" class="header-search__input" placeholder="Поиск">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/vs0dmRq/search.png" class="header-search__icon header-icon" alt="">
</form>
```

Comment: отличный ответ. спасибо. но старые браузеры отбросить нельзя.